# How do I resize a ScatterChart made with ObjC PNChart library in Swift to fit inside a subview?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, scatter-plot

I'm new to Swift and keep getting stuck when trying to create charts. After trying a few of the other swift options (Swift Charts, ios charts, PNChart-swift) and always running into headaches, I'm giving the ObjC PNChart library a try. So far it is looking like the easiest to use and cleanest charting library I've tried, but I am struggling to size the charts it produces into a subview.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
@IBOutlet weak var focusDurationTime: UIView?
let scatterChart: PNScatterChart = PNScatterChart(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, focusDurationTime!.frame.size.width, focusDurationTime!.frame.size.height))

scatterChart.setAxisXWithMinimumValue(0, andMaxValue: 20, toTicks: 6)
scatterChart.setAxisYWithMinimumValue(0, andMaxValue: 50, toTicks: 5)

let fakeX = [2,3,5,6,5,4,3,6,10,3]
let fakeY = [4,7,3,2,5,7,9,1,5,10]

let data01: PNScatterChartData = PNScatterChartData()
data01.strokeColor = PNGreen
data01.fillColor = PNFreshGreen
data01.size = 2
data01.itemCount = UInt(dataSeries1X.count)
data01.inflexionPointStyle = PNScatterChartPointStyle.Circle

data01.getData = ({(index: UInt) -> PNScatterChartDataItem in
    let yValue:CGFloat = CGFloat(fakeY[Int(index)])
    let xValue:CGFloat = CGFloat(fakeX[Int(index)])
    let item = PNScatterChartDataItem(x: xValue, andWithY: yValue)
    return item
})

scatterChart.chartData = [data01]

focusDurationTime?.addSubview(scatterChart)
```

Where `focusDurationTime` is a (poorly named) subview. If I change the size of the `CGRectMake` in the second line then the chart just crops instead of resizing. My situation is pretty similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033812/how-do-i-use-getdata-to-plot-a-linechart-with-objc-pnchart-library-in-swift). In the answer the OP provided he ends with "Now the problem is that the graph does not fit in the subview, but maybe I will open another question since the original post is solved." So I know I'm not the first to run into this problem, but the OP never did open another question.

I would love any guidance.

Comment: Glancing at the source for PNScatterChart, it looks like you may need to call `setup` and then set `needsDisplay` to `true`. Both on your `scatterChart` object. Lemme know if this works.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks so much!  I added scatterChart.setup() and everything started acting as expected. I don't know if the setNeedsDisplay() actually did anything.

Comment: Okay, cool! Glad that helped. I wasn't sure if it would actually need needsDisplay, but I put it down just to be safe.